# Python string in exception converted to tuple

Tags: python, string, exception, tuples

Python 2.7.10 appears to be converting my string into a tuple when thrown in an exception. Here's my example:

```
class MyError(RuntimeError):
   def __init__(self, arg):
      self.args = arg

def raiseMyError():
    errorCode = 29
    errorText = 'Port not ready yet'
    exitCodeMessage = 'ERROR {0}: {1}'.format(errorCode, errorText)
    # print exitCodeMessage  --> print out here and it's a string
    raise MyError(str(exitCodeMessage))

try:
    raiseMyError()

except MyError as e:
    print e.args
```

I create a string containing the error code and description and use this to construct a purpose built exception class. When I print out the `exitCodeMessage` variable before the exception is created I get what I'd expect:

```
ERROR 29: Port not ready yet
```

However, the trace from within the exception handler gives me the following:

```
('E', 'R', 'R', 'O', 'R', ' ', '2', '9', ':', ' ', 'P', 'o', 'r', 't', ' ', 'n', 'o', 't',
' ', 'r', 'e', 'a', 'd', 'y', ' ', 'y', 'e', 't')
```

Can anyone tell me what's going on here and what I can do about it?

Comment: `class MyError(RuntimeError):pass`

Answer (score 3):

Actually you don't need to override the `__init__` method at all, it's sufficient enough to:

```
class MyError(RuntimeError):
   pass
```

Regarding the behaviour - [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.BaseException.args) state that `args` is:

> The tuple of arguments given to the exception constructor.

When you inherit from `Exception` class or any of it's children printing `e.args` will simply print `tuple(e.args)`, since `args` property is defined in such way in the `Exception` class (see @advance512 answer).

When you don't inherit from `Exception`:

```
class MyError:

    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.args = arg
```

you don't inherit the "magic" behind the `args`, thus calling `e.args` will work as expected.

You could also write like this (note **self.arg** instead of **self.args**):

```
class MyError(RuntimeError):

   def __init__(self, arg):
      self.arg = arg
```

and calling `e.arg` will also work as expected.

Comment: That's true. However, I'm interested to understand why in this case it is making this conversion. I noticed also that if I do not inherit from `RuntimeError` but keep the rest of the code as is, it works fine, so presumably there is something in `RuntimeError` which causes this.

Comment: The behaviour is exactly the same whether you inherit from the `RuntimeError` or `Exception`.

Comment: I should have clarified that I change the code so that `MyError` didn't inherit from anything (i.e. `class MyError:`) and it worked as I'd expected. As you say, my `__init__` is not necessary here.

Comment: See my edit for the explanation, I hope it's clear now ;)

Comment: Makes perfect sense now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is because args is a property that is defined in the `BaseException` class.

Check out exceptions.py:70:

`args = property(lambda self: tuple())`

Try this:

```
class MyError(RuntimeError):
   def __init__(self, errorString):
      self._errorString = errorString

def raiseMyError():
    errorCode = 29
    errorText = 'Port not ready yet'
    exitCodeMessage = 'ERROR %s: %s' % (errorCode, errorText)
    # print exitCodeMessage  --> print out here and it's a string
    raise MyError(exitCodeMessage)

try:
    raiseMyError()

except MyError as e:
    print e._errorString
    print e.args
```

output:

```
ERROR 29: Port not ready yet
()
```